# ng-model update not visible in the UI for inupt type file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying a very simple example. I have a file field and text field. Once the file selected, its value need to be updated in the text box.

My code looks like below

```
<input id="selectedFiles" type="text" ng-model="selectedFiles" placeholder="No file(s) chosen">

<input id="file" type="file" name="file" multiple  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileChange()">
```

I know ng-change does not work for the input-type file, so I have used onchange method like above

On the javascript side my code looks like

```
$scope.selectedFiles = "";
$scope.fileChange = function () {
    file = document.getElementById("file");
    $scope.selectedFiles = file.value;
}
```

I am updating the value model value in onchange, but in UI it is not reflecting although input is binded through `slectedFiles` variable.

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/wgjy1wcq/2/)

What should I do so the value reflects in the UI?

Comment: Doesn't look like it is supported: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap the body of your `fileChange` function with a call to `$scope.$apply`. Angular will otherwise not test whether the model has changed.

```
$scope.selectedFiles = "";
$scope.fileChange = function () {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        file = document.getElementById("file");
        $scope.selectedFiles = file.value;
    });
}
```

Comment: It's working. Your fiddle is just not initializing AngularJS properly. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wgjy1wcq/6/